# Adaptar código para usar archivos .py en lugar de los .ui de QtDesigner

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, interfaz-gráfica, exe

¡Buen día!
Tengo este código en que estoy utilizando archivos ".ui" (Los cuales estoy cargando con la instruccion loadUi) y para poder generar un ".exe" con Pyinstaller necesito convertir todos mis archivos ".ui" a ".py" (con lo cual no tuve problema), pero ahora no sé como cambiar mi código de forma que use los archivos ".py" en lugar de los ".ui".

Espero me puedan ayudar, Salu2.

```
import LogoTec_rc
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Principal, self).__init__()
        loadUi('GUIUnidad4.ui', self)
        self.Boton1.clicked.connect(self.abrirTrapecioSimple)
        self.Boton2.clicked.connect(self.abrirTrapecioMultiple)
        self.Boton3.clicked.connect(self.abrirSimpson13)

    def abrirTrapecioSimple(self):
        #Metodo para poder abrir desde un boton la ventana
    def abrirTrapecioMultiple(self):
        #Metodo para poder abrir desde un boton la ventana
    def abrirSimpson13(self):
        #Metodo para poder abrir desde un boton la ventana

#Clase para el método del Trapecio Simple
class TrapecioSimple(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TrapecioSimple, self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi('TrapecioSimple.ui', self)
        self.Boton.clicked.connect(self.TrapSimp)
        self.Boton3.clicked.connect(self.abrirVentanaPrincipal)
    def TrapSimp(self):
        #Aqui va solo parte de un algoritmo
    def abrirVentanaPrincipal(self):
        self.parent().show()
        self.close()
#Clase para el método del Trapecio Multiple
class TrapecioMultiple(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TrapecioMultiple, self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi('TrapecioMult.ui', self)
        self.Boton.clicked.connect(self.TrapMult)
        self.Boton3.clicked.connect(self.abrirVentanaPrincipal)
    def TrapMult(self):
        #Aqui va solo parte de un algoritmo
    def abrirVentanaPrincipal(self):
        self.parent().show()
        self.close()
#Clase para el método de Simpson 1/3
class Simpson13(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Simpson13, self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi('Simpson.ui', self)
        self.Boton.clicked.connect(self.Simp13)
        self.Boton3.clicked.connect(self.abrirVentanaPrincipal)
    def Simp13(self):
        #Aqui va solo parte de un algoritmo
    def abrirVentanaPrincipal(self):
        self.parent().show()
        self.close()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = Principal()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_()) #A veces no se utiliza esta linea para los programas pero en mi caso es NECESARIA ya que si ella no ejecuta de forma correcta.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay generalmente dos aproximaciones, composición o herencia múltiple. La que menos cambios probablemente requiera en tu aplicación sea ésta última. Para los ejemplos voy a usar tu clase `TrapecioSimple` y su `TrapecioSimple.ui`, sería lo mismo para el resto.

### Darles un nombre apropiado al widget principal en QtDesigner

No es imprescindible, pero si muy recomendable que le des un nombre apropiado a las instancias de MainWindow en tu caso en QtDesigner:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ésto facilitará luego la importación, la legibilidad y evitará solapamientos. Por defecto el objeto se llama `MainWindow` en tu caso (`Dialog`, `Widget`, etc dependiendo de que uses), lo que generará una clase llamada `Ui_MainWindow` en todos los caso, pero nos interesaría que cada .ui generara una clase con nombre distintivo, como `Ui_TrapecioSimple`, `Ui_TrapecioDoble`, etc.

### Generamos el .py mediante `pyuic5` (PyQt) / `pyside2-uic` (PySide2)

```
$ pyuic TrapecioSimple.ui -o trapecio_simple.ui
```

---

```
$ pyside2-uic -x TrapecioSimple.ui -o trapecio_simple.ui
```

### Importar la clase en nuestro módulo

Colocamos el .py en el mismo directorio que tu módulo principal o en subdirectorios, pero hay que tenerlo en cuenta para los imports.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from trapecio_simple import Ui_TrapecioSimple
```

Si no le has cambiado el nombre, en tu caso la clase del módulo importado se llamará `Ui_MainWindow` por defecto. Como vas a importar varios archivos, no puedes usar ésta forma o se solaparían, puedes usar un alias:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from trapecio_simple import Ui_MainWindow as Ui_TrapecioSimple
```

### Usar herencia múltiple para unirlo todo

```
class TrapecioSimple(QMainWindow, Ui_TrapecioSimple):
    def __init__(self, *args, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)  # Método setupUi heredado de Ui_TrapecioSimple

    # Resto igual
```

---

Aclarar que **no es realmente necesario convertir a .py para usar un freezer** como PyInstaller o cx_freeze, el .ui se puede usar sin problemas siempre que lo incluyamos correctamente en el ejecutable como recurso y resolvamos la ruta de forma adecuada en el módulo que lo usa.